# Authentication with firebase and angular. How to navigate to other component after the user log in?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to authenticate a site that is written in Angular, with the help of firebase.
I found a guide that describes in a detailed and clear way how to do it.
Website address: https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-7-firebase-authentication-system/

The github that the guide attached:https://github.com/SinghDigamber/angularfirebase-authentication

I followed the instructions but i didn't succeed to navigate to other component  after the user logs in (The user remains on the same page).
 when I ran the code from the github, I encountered the same problem.

Partial code from auth.service.ts:

```
  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    alert(":)");
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

Why the user does not navigate to dashboard component after login?

What could be the cause of the problem? Thank you.

EDIT:
I'll add the code here that I think is relevant:
auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
//import { User } from "../services/user";
//import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export interface User {
  email: string;
} 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data
  authStateSubs: any;
  //authStateSubs: any;

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public auth: AngularFireAuth,  
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {

    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        alert("after signInWithEmailAndPassword");
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          alert("after ngZone.run");
          this.router.navigate(['/authorized-zone']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }


  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }



  /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
  sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
  provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
  SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.email}`);
    const userData: User = {
      email: user.email,
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }

  // Sign out 
  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
  }
}
```

auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ){ }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigate(['login'])
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no mate, there are no errors in the console.You have an idea what the problem is? @julianobrasil

Comment: Is the navigate method being called (the code inside `ngZone.run`)?

Comment: Great test idea! I just checked, and i think the code inside ngZone.run is being called . (I wrote an alert there , and it showed up after login). Do you have an idea why the navigate doesn't work? @julianobrasil

Comment: Hum... there seems to be something wrong with your routes config. Can you post your routes? Maybe put together a minimum reproduction of just the routing part with dummy components in https://stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to wait navigation result with promise, maybe it never happens

```js
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']).then(succeeded => {
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    });
```

you can use async/await to simplify promise code, in example

```js
    async signIn(email, password) {
      alert(":)");
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      const succeeded = await this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);

      if (succeeded) {
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }
    }
```

try to fork [these example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firesbase-signup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fservices%2Flogin.service.ts) and replace `environment.ts` with your own settings and test how it work

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do something based on sign-in and sign-out, a simple and good way is use a subscription to authState. Do it in your service's constrictor. 
You do not do any thing inside signInWithEmailAndPassword's then.

```
constructor(
    public auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    //... 
    ){
        this.authStateSubs=this.auth.authState.subscribe(fbUser=>{
           //this is a Sign in. 
           if( fbUser && fbUser.uid){ 
                this.router.navigate(['/wherever_you_want']);
           }else{
            //Sign out. Go to sign-in page. 
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It didn't work for me, I got into the "if( fbUser && fbUser.uid)" condition before I entered the password (I wrote an alert there). And the page still didn't navigate to the page I wanted.You have an idea what the problem is? Thanks! @Max Hesari

Answer (score 1):

I think have to saving user data in localStorage when before navigate.

```js
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          alert("after ngZone.run");
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result.user));
          this.router.navigate(['/authorized-zone']);
        });
```

if not, the localStorage is null and guarded when navigating.